# Javascript - Get an object the owner of a property or function

Tags: javascript, callback, owner

I pass the callback to setTimeout and internally I need to determine who owns this callback. For example:

```js
class Test1 {
    func1() {
        console.log('test1');
    }

    complete() {
        console.log('complete');
    }
}

function test2() {
    console.log('test2');
}

function timeout(callback, delay) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback();
        callback.getOwner()?.complete();
    }, delay);
}
```

In this case, I need to return the owner of this callback in order to execute the complete () function.

```js
let obj = new Test1();

timeout(obj.func1.bind(obj));
timeout(test2);
```

I understand that complete() can be done inside func1(), like this:

```js
class Test1 {
    func1() {
        console.log('test1');
        this.complete();
    }

    complete() {
        console.log('complete');
    }
}
```

But this is just a small example.

Comment: Functions aren't "owned" by anything. (If you mean the context of a bound function, that is not accessible from outside). If you want to call the `complete` method, you should just pass the whole `obj` as an argument to your `timeout` function.

Comment: "*But this is just a small example.*" - then can you tell us more about [the actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/183280), please?

Comment: These are the classes of the processes that serve the application. They run on a random timeout depending on the user's actions. At the same time, the processes cannot be executed in parallel, they are executed sequentially and are inserted into the queue, they wait until the previous action ends. To do this, there is the Complete () function, which sets up the queue and starts the next process for execution. Programmers sometimes forget to write Complete () and, accordingly, the queue stops working.

Comment: **Functions aren't "owned" by anything.** Bad. I thought that with the introduction of Classes this should have been. it is in other programming languages.

Comment: The introduction of `class` syntax didn't change anything about how methods and prototype inheritance works - that's also why you need to `.bind()` them as usual.

Comment: I don't get what your `complete` method does though. Are you saying the processes are asynchronous and `complete` is actually a callback passed to their methods? And is that `timeout` meant to represent your queue? It might help if you could post your actual code (of the queue and the process interface, ignoring what the processes do exactly).

Comment: No) The code will give absolutely nothing. This is not one class of 50 lines, at least several classes are used to perform these actions, or rather 6 main ones and a dozen additional ones)